# Python order filling loop?

Tags: python, loops

Let's say I have a bunch of orders I need to fill

```
orders = [39.789032, 36.023618, 3.0539913, 20.0, 1.314, 2.5, 0.401, 1.0, 1.989, 6.3254668, 0.5]
```

I have a starting volume of say 100

```
startingvolume = 100
```

I want to iterate through the orders until my volume/order is filled

so the first order would be my initial 100 minus the first order of 39.789032 which leaves 60.2110968 of my order still to be filled. What is the most Pythonic way to fill my order until my starting volume is 0?

Comment: Is this homework?

Comment: This looks like the knapsack problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Knapsack_problem. Its an extremely difficult problem, many great minds have worked on it and not solved it.

Comment: I think that this question is quite good. Enven though, it can be a homework, but it's still a good exercice. I like it :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NumPy makes this easy.

```
import numpy as np

def fill(orders, startingvolume):
    orders = np.asarray(orders)
    return orders[orders.cumsum() <= startingvolume]
```

Given your example inputs, that will return:

```
array([ 39.789032 ,  36.023618 ,   3.0539913,  20.       ])
```

Which are the orders you've filled completely.  To get the one remaining one that you partially filled:

```
orders[orders.cumsum() >= startingvolume][0]
```

Comment: Within my solution, i found that the best order to fill is `(39.789032, 36.023618, 3.0539913, 20.0, 1.0)` which can fill `99.86664 from 100`. Your best order is missing one element which is `1.0`.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of ways, here's one:

```
orders = [39.789032, 36.023618, 3.0539913, 20.0, 1.314, 2.5, 0.401, 1.0, 1.989, 6.3254668, 0.5]
startingvolume = 100

for i in range(len(orders)):
    qty = startingvolume if startingvolume < orders[i] else orders[i]
    orders[i] -= qty
    startingvolume -= qty
    if not startingqty:
        break
```

This will deduct as much as possible from each order until there's nothing left then stop.

Answer (score 0):

You can solve your question using `combinations` from `itertools` module and `max()`, like this example:

```
from itertools import combinations

orders = [39.789032, 36.023618, 3.0539913, 20.0, 1.314, 2.5, 0.401, 1.0, 1.989, 6.3254668, 0.5]
startingvolume = 100

sub = []
for k in range(1, len(orders)):
    sub.append(max([[j, sum(j)] for j in combinations(orders, k) if sum(j) <= startingvolume], key = lambda x: x[1]))

best_order, fill_max = max(sub, key = lambda x: x[1])
print("best order is: {}\nMax to fill from starting volume is: {}"
                                    .format(best_order, fill_max))
```

Output:

```
best order is: (39.789032, 36.023618, 3.0539913, 20.0, 1.0)
Max to fill from starting volume is: 99.86664
```

Answer (score -1):

Use the for loop.
If you don't know what that is, you should download an app, or search YouTube for the basics of python. I recommend thenewboston's programming tutorials.